# No matches when searching for "latex" in a PDF when \LaTeX was used

Tags: pdftex, pdf, copy-paste

If I use `pdflatex` to produce a PDF from the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX
\end{document}
```

then searching for the string `latex` in [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) yields zero matches.  [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) does find a match, and the search results sidebar makes it clear that it's finding `L A TEX` (spaces between the L, A, and TEX).  If I search for `l a tex` (with spaces) in Okular then it does find a match.

Is there something I can do so that a case-insensitive search for `latex` always finds a match?

More generally, is it possible to assign HTML-like "alt text" to the output of arbitrary LaTeX commands so that searching for the text finds a match where the command's ink appears?

Comment: Perhaps something like [cmap](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmap?lang=en) is what you are looking for? Or [accsupp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/accsupp)?

Comment: This is strongly dependent on the PDF viewer; for instance, Skim is perfectly able to find LaTeX, as [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4BPpi.png) shows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\parindent 0pt
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\let\ORIGlatex\LaTeX
\renewcommand{\LaTeX}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=plain, ActualText=LaTeX}%
  \ORIGlatex
  \EndAccSupp{}}
\begin{document}

\ORIGlatex

\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Note that the status of the package [`accsupp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) is still said to be 'experimental'. (So, I suppose that means you should experiment with this answer....)